# Absolute Temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature

I'll make the question short.
I might be misunderstanding this I have limited physics knowledge.
So is there an absolute temperature? I know there is an absolute zero temperature but I am assuming since particles can only be so kinetically charged that there should be a terminal velocity of them.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a maximum possible temperature? If so, the answer is no.

Comment: I cannot understand what you are asking - you need to be more specific.

Comment: I am asking if there is a hottest temperature. So my logic in asking this in my limited physics knowledge is that temperature is equivalent to kinetic energy / velocity(Ekin is directly proportional to massvelocity^2) in gases. There is an absolute terminal velocity of all particles. Therefore there should be an absolute terminal kinetic energy and absolute highest temperature for specific substances given their masses.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you're right , O Kelvin is the absolute zero of temperature .

The particles have the lowest vibrational motion, containing only quantum mechanical and zero-point energy-induced particle motion.

The temperature of a system is simply related to the amount of energy in that system. Because the system can't have a negative energy, there is only so much heat you can remove from it and so a limit to how cold you can get. This is called absolute zero. We've got very close to it. Scientists in Finland have cooled rhodium atoms to a 10th of a billionth of a degree above absolute zero.

On the other hand, an absolute maximum temperature would require there to be a limit to the amount of energy you can give to a particle. As far as we know, there is no such limit. Although the speed of light is the universal speed limit, the reason you can't get there is that this would require an infinite amount of energy. So this speed limit does not limit the amount of energy and therefore, the temperature of an individual particle

Source - https://www.thenakedscientists.com/articles/questions/there-absolute-maximum-temperature

Comment: infinite energy?

Comment: The limit is not defined as of now since the speed of a particle's limit is the speed of light , to reach this speed, enormous amounts of energy would have to be supplied for particle reach such a limit , that amount of energy is similar to infinite energy ,hence the answer.

Answer (score 2):

While an intuitive definition of temperature is the "average kinetic energy of a particle," that is not the most general definition. The formal definition of temperature is
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{k_B T} = \frac{\partial S}{\partial E}
\end{equation}
where $S$ is the entropy, $E$ is energy, $T$ is temperature, and $k_B$ is Boltzmann's constant. The temperature will become infinite if $\partial S/\partial E = 0$.

Using the intuitive definition, we would expect the entropy to be a growing function of energy. This is because as the energy of the system increases, a particle has more available states that it can occupy (roughly speaking, the particle is able to move faster and faster as the energy increases). In turn, that leads us to expect $\partial S / \partial E > 0$. This would allow the temperature to be arbitrarily large, but never infinite (or negative). This is consistent with the observation made by Aarushi Agarwal in their answer, that the kinetic energy of a particle can be arbitrarily large (even though its speed is bounded by the speed of light).

However, there are counter-intuitive systems where $\partial S/\partial E$ can be zero or even negative (meaning that *negative* temperatures are allowed). Here is an plot of the entropy vs energy for an idealized two-state system, this image is taken from the [wikipedia article on negative temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_temperature)

[image]

While this example is based on an ideal system, systems like this have been created in the lab.

At the maximum of this curve, $\partial S/\partial E=0$, and so the temperature is infinite there.